# Node API MongoDB Query - How can I return the mongoDB query to the client?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

Being new to JS I decided to throw my self into the deep end with some Node API development. I am experimenting with querying my mongoDB.

I currently have an **index.js** script for the API using the 'express' module. For a GET request I want to return the query results in an array/json as a response. I am importing the mongoDB query from another script I made called **db_functions.js**.

**I have tried messing with the functions, trying to add return statements or something just to be get the query function I wrote to return an array. I have probably spent too much time on this issue already and its probably something simple that I didn't do.**

I have a GET request looking like the following:

```
app.get('/db_query', function (req, res) {

    var result = db_functions.return_query();
    res.send(result)
});
```

I have experimented with some code I found at **w3schools**  here: https://www.w3schools.com/nodejs/nodejs_mongodb_query.asp

It displays the result in the console but I want to return the result in an array to the client response.

```
const  db_url = "mongodb://localhost:27017/";
const  client = MongoClient(db_url, { useNewUrlParser:  true, useUnifiedTopology:  true })

  
function  return_query() {
    client.connect(function(err, db) {
        if (err) throw  err;
        var  db_var = db.db("test_db");
        db_var.collection("simple_data").find({}).toArray(function(err, result) {
            if (err) throw  err;
            console.log(result);
            db.close()
        });
    });
};
```

I want the client response to look like the one in the console.log shown below:

```
[
    {
    "_id": "6015c1c74fb541419e145db1",
    "name": "George",
    "phone": "00011333"
    },
    {
    "_id": "6015c1c74fb541419e145db2",
    "name": "John",
    "phone": "9911999"
    }
]
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: maybe try to write `return result` instad of the console.log

Comment: What is the result you are getting from res.send(result)?

Comment: @Omer I tried putting `return result` instead of the console.log. That did not help unfortunately. I played around with a lot of configurations but didnt find a solution

Comment: @Koodies the result from res.send(result) is nothing. It is blank.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to return the query response using a callback function:

```js
function  return_query(my_callback) {
    client.connect(function(err, db) {
        if (err) throw  err;
        var  db_var = db.db("test_db");
        db_var.collection("simple_data").find({}).toArray(function(err, result) {
            if (err) throw  err;
            console.log(result);
            my_callback(result)
            db.close()
        });
    });
};
```

and in your express server file:

```js
app.get('/db_query', function (req, res) {

    db_functions.return_query(function(result) {
      res.send(result)
    });
    
});
```

**Explanation**

The query to your mongo database is asynchronous, which means the result is not coming back immediatly.

There are actually already two callback functions nested in your return_query function. One for the connection to the database and then, inside that, another one for retrieving the query response. This is why you can not simply return the response using the `return` keyword. The `return` keyword is bound to the closest (callback) function scope it is in.

If you get the (understandable) feeling that these callbacks get complicated quickly I recommend having a look at **promises** and **async** functions. They make working with asynchronous code in javascript and nodejs much easier.

Comment: Thank you! It worked! Gave me some more insight. I will try and learn the deal about callbacks and such.

Comment: Glad I could help! With express and mongodb you are on track for a versatile software architecture.

Comment: Appreciate it! That is the goal! I work with Python on the daily and need to touch on node and js for a project outside of work.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to show the results with a get service and show it to client when they request it?

Because your code is running at the start and now its time to write a rest api service and send the result to client.

Comment: Yes, thats what I want it to do. I have written the API and it works with the imported function that queries the database. I just need to be able to return the results from the query to the client

Comment: I have shared my GET request code above above and the mongoDB query function that I imported above